# Pasar de una Aplicación a otra, especificando la Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

A lo que hago referencia es que, desde la **Aplicación 1**, viaje hasta la **Aplicación 2** pero no a la **primera Activity** (de la segunda aplicación), sino, que llegue directamente a una **segunda Activity** (de la segunda aplicación).

**Aplicación 1**: Esta aplicación solo recibe un dato ingresado por el usuario, por medio de un EditText y al dar click en el botón pasa directamente a la segunda aplicación y me manda dicho dato.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText et_emisor;
private TextView tv_receptor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_emisor = findViewById(R.id.et_emisor);
    tv_receptor = findViewById(R.id.tv_receptor);

    Ok();
}

public void metodo_Comun(View v) { //Método del botón

    //Implementación del Intent para mandar el dato que recoge del EditText, hacia la segunda aplicación:
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.secundario");
    intent.putExtra("emisor", et_emisor.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void Ok() { //Método que recibe el dato de la segunda aplicación
    Intent i = getIntent();
    tv_receptor.setText(i.getStringExtra("emisor2"));
}
```

**Aplicación 2**: Esta aplicación recibe el dato enviado de la **Aplicación 1** y lo sitúa en el TextView, asi confirma que el viaje de datos fue exitoso.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tv_receptor2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv_receptor2 = findViewById(R.id.tv_receptor);


    //Recibe el dato enviado de lo primera aplicación y lo situa en el componente tv_receptor2
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    tv_receptor2.setText(intent.getStringExtra("emisor"));
}


//Implementación del método onBackPressed, es decir, que cuando le doy atrás, me recoja el dato que envié de la 
// primera aplicación y me lo devuelva a la primera aplicación y lo situe en el 
// componente tv_receptor (de la primera aplicación).
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    String dato = tv_receptor2.getText().toString();
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("emisor2", dato);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

Cabe recalcar que aquí no pego ninguna segunda Activity (de la segunda Aplicación), ya que no tengo nada ahí y esa sería la idea principal de la pregunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo puedes solucionar añadiendo esta línea a tu Intent:

```
Intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.segundaaplicacion", "com.segundaaplicacion.NombreDeTuActividad"));
```

Quedando así:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.segundaaplicacion", "com.segundaaplicacion.NombreDeTuActividad"));
intent.putExtra("emisor", et_emisor.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar debes declarar la Segunda Actividad en el Manifest de la Aplicacion 2, es importante poner la propiedad exported a true ya que si no vas a tener un error:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:exported="true">
    </activity>
```

Despues puedes acceder desde la Aplicacion 1 de la siguiente forma:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setClassName("com.example.secundario", "com.example.secundario.SecondActivity");
        intent.putExtra("emisor", et_emisor.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

Comment: Es valida tu respuesta pero mi idea no es omitir la primera Activity. Igualmente, muchas gracias.

Comment: @MateoContreras No tienes porque omitir la primera activity, de esta forma estás navegando de la Activity de la aplicación 1 a la segunda Activity de la aplicación 2 tal y como específicas en la pregunta. El código que te mando lo he probado simulando tu caso :)